# Python Regex, word in between two words matches correctly, but not with dot

Tags: python, regex

I know that `.` is a metacharacter which I have to escape when I want to search for it. 
So I am doing:

```
import re

fileName = "A011C009_140914_FPS025/Proxy/A011C009_140914_FPS25.1001.jpg"
regExpression = "FPS([^\\]]+)\\."
m = re.findall(regExpression, fileName)

myString = m[0]
print(myString.strip("0"))
```

I expect the result to be **25** but I get **25/Proxy/A011C009_140914_FPS25.1001**

Searching for another metacharacter `/` works fine:

```
regExpression = "FPS([^\\]]+)\\/Proxy"
m = re.findall(regExpression, fileName)
```

Comment: Use Ctrl + K to indent your code. Don't use quote - it will destroy your new lines and indent.

Comment: you want 025 and 25 both???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex should be:

```
regExpression = "FPS([^./]+)\\."
```

**Code:**

```
import re

fileName = "A011C009_140914_FPS025/Proxy/A011C009_140914_FPS25.1001.jpg"
regExpression = "FPS([^./]+)\\."

print ( re.findall(regExpression, fileName) )
['25']
```

Comment: can you explain the regex a bit?

Comment: Yes sure. This regex matches `FPS` followed by a negation based regex i.e `[^./]+` which matches text until `.` or `/` is found and `\\.` just matches a literal dot afterwards. `([^./]+)` captures this text in a captured group #1.

Answer (score 1):

How about the regex

`FPS([^\/]+)\/`

would match `025` which follows `FPS` in the string.

```
>>> regExpression = "FPS([^\/]+)\/"
>>> m = re.findall(regExpression, fileName)
>>> print m
['025']
```

Comment: can you explain the regex?

Comment: @user1767754 `[^\/]` matches anything other than /. and quantifier `+` ensures one or more occurence of that anything. which is then followed by /. in string , `FPS025/` is matched by the regex, and match group 1 corresponds to `025`